# Forbid letters in number field in html5

Tags: html, forms, input

I want to prevent the user from entering non-numeric characters in a textfield for telephone number in HTML5.  I tried this, but it doesn't forbid non-numeric characters:

```
<input type="tel"  name="usrtel"><br>
```

I tried using `type=number` as well, but that gives me a up and a down arrow to increase or decrease the value, which is not useful for telephone numbers.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean? `type="tel"` already constraints "numbers" only. Do you want a numpad instead?

Comment: You may try the [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern), it won't forbid usering from entering, but it will forbid forms from submitting.

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, `type="tel"` does *not* impose syntactic restrictions: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#telephone-state-%28type=tel%29

Comment: Bear in mind that there's a *reason* it doesn't impose restrictions. My phone number could plausibly be "+44 (0)117 496 0948 ext. 1234", for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`pattern`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute) attribute with a regex `\d*`

```
<input type="tel" name="usrtel" pattern="\d*" />
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SENW7/) (*After typing in the box, just click anywhere outside the box, if you type in anything except the integers, it will show a red box, else it will stay normal*)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/SENW7/1/) (With custom message and submit button)

---

As you commented, you can change your `pattern` value to `^[0-9]{3,45}$` where user will have to input minimal of *3* digits to maximum of *45* in length.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SENW7/3/)

```
<input 
      type="tel" 
      name="usrtel" 
      pattern="^[0-9]{3,45}$" 
      title="You can only enter numbers, with a minimal of 3 characters 
      upto 45 characters are accepted."
      required="required" 
/>
```

In the above markup, am using a `title` which will throw a custom error to your user.

Comment: Thank You @Mr. Alien worked for me....can u help me with setting the min and max number to input into the text field...thanxx

Comment: I think you should add a `title` attribute into the code in the answer, since it is crucial for making error messages understandable (and may give a useful hint on mouseover).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for reminding me :) I've added that in the demo 2, but didn't pasted the markup here :) doing it now...